# How to measure usability/devxp of a sdk?

Tags: usability

We have a SDK/framework that people can use to build end user facing apps.
I would like to know if there are any standard metrics/surveys etc. that I can use to measure the usability/developer experience of using the SDK ?

I did some google searching and most of the resources are about APIs and also they focus on runtime system qualities (performance, stability..).

Any pointers or experience that could share ?

Comment: There's only one: "WTF/Minute"! http://i.imgur.com/J1svNp7.jpg (looks funny but there is a lot of truth in it)